# System requirements for ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, system-requirements

I am a new one so i would like to tell me which version of Ubuntu should i install.I prefer do the installation from the Windows.My laptop has an Intel(R) Core(TM) Duo processor 2.1GH , 4 GB RAM and i have windows 7.

Comment: Ubuntu is an operating system. I don't recommend installing an operating system from within another operating system. There's no reason you can't dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu and this is what I would recommend for you based on your question. the system specs you provided indicate that you should be able to run whatever version of Ubuntu you want. which version or flavour is a matter of opinion however exceeding minimum system requirements will lead to better performance. Ubuntu will install alongside Windows and grub will allow you to shoose which to run at boot time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a bit more info about your system. Check this link to find out your system details: http://www.wikihow.com/Find-out-Your-System-Information

Then go to this page to check out ubuntu minimum system requirements (look at ubuntu desktop): https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Most probably you have the needed requirements to run ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: If you could provide more system info that'd be great, however if you can run Windows 7 you should be pretty good on Ubuntu.